# How to distribute private android application to specific devices?

Tags: applications, alternative-markets

How can I deploy an APK for android that is only available for the devices I specify beforehand?

I would like to a host a private application that is only available to workers inside the company and only for the devices that are owned by the company.

I know I can do this with Google Play, but that requires a G-Suite/Workspace subscription we do not have.

I would like to continuously deploy new versions and the devices to update automatically.

Are there any custom marketplaces that allow this? Anything else?

Comment: As you have already noticed company-stores are usually provided by a MDM solution. F-Droid allows to host [own repos](https://f-droid.org/en/docs/Setup_an_F-Droid_App_Repo/). However as far as I know there is no account/authentication concept, therefore your devices require a private network e.g. via VPN or a company Wifi so that only company devices can install/update the provided app(s).

Comment: @Robert Right now, I am looking into Samsung Knox